# Implementing a rest api using zf3

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework3

I want to build a new REST API for my application on the base of zend framework 3. Because I'm very new in zend two things are a bit misunderstanding for me: I know there's a component named `zf-rest` and I also know how to include it via composer. But how does zf-rest "knows" that I want to work with ZF3?

And then I found some sample applications using zf-rest and some only using `zend-mvc`. So I guess that zend already has a rest implementation. What are the differences between zf-rest and zend-mvc and in which situations should I use which framework?

Comment: I think, this answer might addresses your question the best:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40933115/4375900

Comment: But this article doesn't describe how zf-rest recognizes ZF3.

Comment: Did you are least bothered to read the requirements for the damned package? https://packagist.org/packages/zfcampus/zf-rest

Comment: Yes: zf2/zf3. That's why I asked.

Comment: composer will install the latest compatible version